# View does not fit the canvas on canvas scale

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

When I'm trying to scale my canvas to a draw SCALED view, my view is actually scaled, but view is getting clipped. (probably because of its layout parameters?)

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(2f, 2f);
    view.draw(canvas);
}
```

simple image:

[image]

image after new onDraw called, for example when I click this button:

[image]

The button should be full sized when canvas is scaled. Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

p.s. call of

```
view.invalidate();
view.requestLayout();
```

doesn't help.

---

I'm using `MyDragShadowBuilder` because I want my view to be double sized when I drag the view.

```
private final class MyDragShadowBuilder extends DragShadowBuilder {

        public MyDragShadowBuilder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
            final View view = getView();
            if (view != null) {
                canvas.scale(2f, 2f);
                view.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                Log.e("DragShadowBuilder", "Asked to draw drag shadow but no view");
            }
        }
```

I add my view into my Absolute Layout implementation with WRAP_CONTENT layout properties

Comment: because your canvas has the size of the image and that size was originally set when the image was first laid out. please post how you set the size and respond to onMeasure

Comment: I've made an update..

Comment: the issue is your view has the size of the original view. you have to make it larger before scaling it.

Comment: Do you mean parent view? if so then parent view has FILL_PARENT property and its in the root node of the activity

Comment: 'the original view' I mean the view in the constructor.

Comment: unfortunately resize view in this `onDraw` method dont work. It still has the same result

Comment: I would have used match_parent layout properties in order to have the canvas large enough to host the view

Comment: yes, parent view has already match_parent layout properties

Comment: still, not talking about the parent, but about this view

Comment: oh, Ive already tried.. and even change layout properties by setting high width and height values. it does not work properly

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same trouble. After some time i found a way to make it work :)
This scales the original view by a factor of 4.

```
private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    private static final int SCALING_FACTOR = 4;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        View v = getView();
        final int width = v.getWidth() * SCALING_FACTOR;
        final int height = v.getHeight() * SCALING_FACTOR;
        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(SCALING_FACTOR, SCALING_FACTOR);
        getView().draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Comment: canvas.scale(factor, factor) and overriding onDrawShadow() was exactly what I was missing! Works great.