# scale animation in DragShadowBuilder canvas during drag and drop

Tags: android

How can I create a custom DragShadowBuilder to animate the scaling of a view thats in the canvas instead of it just scaling to a set size?

For example I have an ImageView that is used for drag and drop and when I press on the ImageView the image needs to grow in the canvas thats used for drag and drop that you would see following your finger while you are dragging it to a drop zone.

I am able to get the image to scale to a set size using the following `CustomDragShadowBuilder` class found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155393/1677657) but is there a way to animate the scaling?

```
public static class CustomDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    private static final int SCALING_FACTOR = 4;

    public CustomDragShadowBuilder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        View v = getView();
        final int width = v.getWidth() * SCALING_FACTOR;
        final int height = v.getHeight() * SCALING_FACTOR;
        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(SCALING_FACTOR, SCALING_FACTOR);
        getView().draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution I found is to animate the scale before start the dragging, something like that:

```
    final View yourView;
    ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "scaleX",4f);
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "scaleY",4f);
    AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
    animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
    animSetXY.setDuration(duration);
    final View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);
    animSetXY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            v.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                    new CustomDragShadowBuilder(yourView) ,  // the drag shadow builder
                    null,
                    0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
            );
        }
    });
    animSetXY.start();
```